# Firebase Android App - not updating realtime database

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I experience some errors while trying to push data into my firebase realtime database. I checked a couple of tutorials and according to all of them i am doing nothing wrong. Unfortunately I can not update the database from my android studio emulator device.

I activated debug mode and stepped through every single process and saw that my code actually works because the database responses with the child id when pushing to it.

```
package com.example.fbconnect;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    Button btnsaves;
    Member member;
    DatabaseReference myRef;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        btnsaves=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
        btnsaves.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                myRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Member");
                String id = myRef.push().getKey();
                member = new Member("MSmith", 12, id);
                myRef.child(id).setValue(member);
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

When debugging to this line

```
String id = myRef.push().getKey();
```

I see, that the database answered with a code. But it will not set the new value or update the value of existing database Childs.

After activating the debug mode I recognised some rare lines in android studio that may lead to the problem:

> E/FirebaseInstanceId: Topic sync or token retrieval failed on hard failure exceptions: AUTHENTICATION_FAILED. Won't retry the operation.

I am definitely sure that I did not activate any authentication in my firebase. Normally everybody should be able to read and write (I am aware of this but I am desperate to get this database connection working).

Can you please help me?

Comment: Did you change the authentication of Firebase database in the firebase console?

Comment: no its still on default. I tried activating the anonymous sign in method but that did not help either...

Comment: Go to firebase console > Database > Firebase Realtime Database > Rules tab
Change read and write to true.

Comment: I'm experiencing the same, it works on my physical device but not on the emulator. But it seems to store the data in some local cache since it can retrieve what I've set in the emulator but that's also gone after I close the app.

Comment: For me the problems with the emulator were solved by uninstalling the app from the device and a fresh deploy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to firebase console > Database > Firebase Realtime Database > Rules tab Change read and write to true.
Also check if your device is connected to the internet.

Comment: already did that, sorry thought you meant the general firebase authentication

Comment: Check in the Android studio if it is connected to Firebase database or not.
Also check whether your device is connected to internet or not

Comment: I use the android studio emulator, shouldn't that be connected to the internet anyways?

Comment: Not sure about emulator... Try "Cold Boot Now" in AVD Manager

Comment: you are right...the system settings on the emulated android device show: connected to AndroidWifi, no internet.
did a "Cold Boot Now" - nothing changed

Comment: Try connecting to the internet.. or if you have a physical device.. try using that while connected to the internet

Comment: It works nice thanks a lot. My DNS settings on my Mac were not configured right. Had to insert DNS 8.8.8.8 to connect my emulator to internet.

Comment: Consider accepting the answer if it helped you. I have edited my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 3):

If anyone reads this and gets this error,

> Firebase Realtime Database connection killed: Different Region

Make sure your `google-services.json` file has the right `firebase_url`.

If it doesn't work right away,

1. Clean Project
2. Invalidate Caches

After restart, it should be working if that was the case.

Answer (score 0):

By Default Rule in Firebase is for Authorized requests

you can change read and write to True

**BUT IT IS NOT SECURE**

any one with your Firebase Url Can Access And Change Data

[image]

Comment: I changed those settings to true already. but the app won't connect to the database.